# Nested repeaters - accessing a control inside the parent repeater from the child repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where I list several hotels, and for each hotel I list the prices for each date that the user selected.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrHotels" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td><%# Eval("HotelName") %></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrHotelRates" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetHotelRates(Container.DataItem) %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                        <span class="date"><%# Eval("Date") %></span>
                        <span class="price">$<%# Eval("Price") %></span>
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <td>
                <span class="date">Total</span>
                <span class="price">$<asp:Literal ID="litTotal" runat="server" /></span>
            </td>
        </tr>                   
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

And my code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DateTime startDate = Request.QueryString["StartDate"];
        DateTime endDate = Request.QueryString["EndDate"];

        List<Hotel> hotels = GetHotels(startDate, endDate);
        rptrHotels.DataSource = hotels;
        rptrHotels.DataBind();
    }
}


protected List<Rate> GetHotelRates(object item)
{
    DateTime startDate = Request.QueryString["StartDate"];
    DateTime endDate = Request.QueryString["EndDate"];
    Hotel hotel = (Hotel)item;

    List<Rate> rates = GetRates(hotel, startDate, endDate);

    decimal total = (from r in rates
                     select r.Price).Sum();

    return rates;
}
```

In my GetHotelRates() function, I'm getting the total price by summing up all the rate prices. But I need to somehow put that value in litTotal, which is outside the child repeater, but inside the parent repeater.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

In your item binding event do something like this:

```
((Literal)((Repeater)sender).Parent.FindControl("litTotal")).Text;
```

You might need to do another cast on the parent to get it to a Repeater, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't have an `object sender` variable in my GetHotelRates() function. What do I need to do to add that?

Comment: You would only get that if you had an ItemDataBind event.  Basically every time an item was databound you would use that line of code above.

Comment: it never occurred to me that I could cast the sender as the container repeater! +1 for a great bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try some NamingContainer.Parent.Parent....FindControl (exaggerated) magic, but a cleaner way to do it would be to just create a separate method to get your total:

```
protected decimal GetHotelTotal(object item)
{
    Hotel hotel = (Hotel)item;

    List<Rate> rates = GetRates(hotel, startDate, endDate);

    decimal total = (from r in rates
                 select r.Price).Sum();
    return total;
}
```

And call this in your Literal:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litTotal" runat="server" Text="<%# GetHotelTotal(Container.DataItem) %>" />
```

Comment: Of course, if running GetRates is costly you might want to look into designing that a little differently, either preserving the value across calls or making it part of the Hotel object so it's already there.

Comment: I think I actually like that second approach better.. I would add a property List<Rate> HotelRates to Hotel that is populated by your GetRates. Then you don't have to mess with that at DataBinding time and you have everything ready to be consumed cleanly.